# Having issues installing/running tf2onnx

Tags: python-3.x, tf2onnx

I'm trying to get Tf2onnx to run so that I can convert a saved_model.pb file to onnx format. Nothing is really working out. I have tried installing it with the `pip install git+https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx` command but same issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command should be issued from the site-packages directory, not the tf2onnx directory. I also put a sudo in front which helped.
`sudo python3 -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model /home/isaacpadberg/Desktop/model --output model.onnx`